# ReactJS Table conditional styling based on previous value

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I have a React JS app using Material-UI Table component that looks like this:

[image]

I need to change the style of the border between the last row of the same date and the first row of another date like between `Date A` and `Date B` like this:
[image]

My code to create the table is just a normal map :

```
<TableCell>
                <Typography style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{new Date(row.date).toLocaleDateString().slice(0, 10)}</Typography>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell><Typography noWrap={true} style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{row.user}</Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell><Typography style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{row.duration}h</Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell><Typography style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{row.description}</Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell style={{ width: 35 }} align="left">
                <IconButton
                    className={classes.iconButton}
                    style={{ marginRight: 3 }}
                    onClick={() => openWorklogModalForEdit(row.id, row.date, row.duration, row.description, row.project_id, row.user_id, row.project, row.clientName)}>
                    <EditIcon className={classes.actionsButtonIcon} />
                </IconButton>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell style={{ width: 65 }} align="right" >
                <IconButton
                    className={classes.iconButton}
                    onClick={() => deleteWorklog(row.id)}>
                    <DeleteIcon className={classes.actionsButtonIcon} />
                </IconButton>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class for first table row of different date when using `.map`. Please refer to [this code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_f/1zwLx7qc/20/) for a simple demo.

Thoughts:

1. As you're using `map` to construct a table from an array, the syntax is

```
let newArray = arr.map(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
  // return element for newArray, after executing something
}[, thisArg]);
```

docs: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

2. Then in the map callback body, you have access to current value and index. Then you can check whether the current item is the first of a new 'group', or a new date. If true, you can add a custom class to this row (as the demo is doing).
3. Then you can use css to add the border, so that you can achieve 'conditional styling based on previous value'.

Comment: That code snippet is pretty great, somehow got me to the right path, but I do have another question now:
by checking that `index > 0 && value !== value[index-1]` in my code will be like  `index > 0 && row.date !== row.date[index-1]` it does not get the previous row.date but in gets me the `index-1` character of `row.date` value. How can I overcome this?

Comment: `row.date !== row.date[index-1]` sounds incorrect to me, if `row` is your current item, then the right side we should compare with the last item in the **array**, not `row.date[index - 1]` but `array[index - 1]`

Comment: @VladPopa In my code it's `value != data[index - 1]` not `value !== value[index-1]` :)

Comment: I tried with both `!=` and `!==` but is the same result :(

Comment: @ マークさん Thank you!
In the end I wrote it: `row.date !== initialArray[index-1].date`

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the styling by adding or deleting class on some element this can easily be done.

```
<td className={shouldBeBlack ? 'black' : 'orange'} ></td>
```

so like depending on value of shouldBeBlack you can set css property of the table data or any element. Just depends how u r styling.
If there is some prop you can pass to the material ui element then same c=kind of ternary equation can be made for the same.

Comment: What you've said it good, but it doesn't totally apply to what I need because I don't know how to set and check that `shouldBeBlack` state while mapping

Answer (score 0):

By apply mapping, you can add check like this

```
 rows.map((row,index)=>{
      if(index !== 0)?
          <td className={row.date === rows[index-1].date? 'blackLine' : 'orangeLine'} </td>
      :
       <td className='black'} ></td>
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, as the comments on the accepted answer, I've come up to the same thing :D